# How to delete multi relationship Model in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I have 3 tables

**books**: 
- id
- name
- deleted_at

**posts**: 
- id
- book_id
- connent
- deleted_at

**comments**: 
- id
- post_id
- comment
- deleted_at

A book has many posts, a post has many comments.

I want to delete posts and comments relate to a book when I delete the book.
I already add relationship in all Models, all table use SoftDelete, and try to use Event in Laravel

```
// Book Model
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($book) {
         $book->posts()->delete();
    });
}

// Post Model
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($post) {
         $post->comments()->delete();
    });
}
```

When I try to delete a book:

```
$book = Book:find($bookId);
$book->delete()
```

Book and Posts, deleted, but Comments are not deleted.
Could I delete comments with Laravel Event?
Thank for readding!

Comment: is your book and post deleted from database completely??

Comment: No, I used SoftDelete for all table

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a different variable inside the delete event of your `Post` model.

```
// Post Model
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($post) {
         // $book->comments()->delete();
         $post->comments()->delete();
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, parse wrong name variable. Already edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your model relationships ON DELETE trigger to CASCADE. Otherwise you'll need to iterate the related records and individually delete them.

```
$model->related->each(function ($related) { $related->delete(); });
```

Edit: you have the right idea with model events, but delete posts first and work backwards to books

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($post) {
        $post->comments()->delete();
    });
}
```

Make sure your models all have the soft delete trait and date properties:

```
 use SoftDeletes;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Comment: I have use
     $table->foreign('book_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('books')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade')

But I'm not sure cascade working with  SoftDelete?

Comment: You'll need to manually delete related records or use a library to handle it for you. See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this neat little trait made by michaeldyrynda, called laravel-cascade-soft-deletes.

Sample code from the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Comment;
use Iatstuti\Database\Support\CascadeSoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CascadeSoftDeletes;

    protected $cascadeDeletes = ['comments'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```